# Android, WireMock.stubFor not return stub response

Tags: android, wiremock

I want to return stub response when Android app send http request that contain **/api/Profile/Favorite?value=%7B%22ID%22%3A11821%7D**

So here my test (using WireMock framework)

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ContactsFragmentTransportTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    public ContactsFragmentTransportTest() {
        super(ContactsFragment.class);
    }

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);


    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();     

        WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8089));
        wireMockServer.start();
        WireMock.configureFor("127.0.0.1", wireMockServer.port());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendRequestEspresso() throws Exception {
        stubFor(get(urlMatching("/api/Profile/Favorite?value=%7B%22ID%22%3A11821%7D"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody("{This_is_mock_response}")));

        // some code that send http request
    }
}
```

But when I start test method **testSendRequestEspresso** I get production response from production server.

Here request from Android device:

```
http://mycompany.com/api/Profile/Favorite?value=%7B%22ID%22%3A11821%7D
```

Here response:

```
 StatusCode = 200
 HEADERS = 

 [Cache-Control = no-cache]
 [Connection = Keep-Alive]
 [Content-Length = 41]
 [Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8]
 [Date = Thu, 29 Jun 2017 14:10:42 GMT]
 [Expires = -1]
 [Pragma = no-cache]
 [Server = Microsoft-IIS/8.5]
 [X-Android-Received-Millis = 1498745395359]
 [X-Android-Response-Source = NETWORK 200]
 [X-Android-Selected-Protocol = http/1.1]
 [X-Android-Sent-Millis = 1498745395320]
 [X-AspNet-Version = 4.0.30319]
 [X-Powered-By = ASP.NET]


 BODY = {"Code":"CodeSuccess","Message":"Succes"}
```

As you can see I'm NOT get stub response: **{This_is_mock_response}** from WireMock.
Why?

Comment: did your problem got resolved? I am facing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

the baseurl for your request should have been 
`http://127.0.0.1:8089`. because that is where you set the mock right?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this an attempt to answer or a question for clarity?